# How to multiply array elements by condition

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I have a array and want to multiply the elements greater than 9 by 2 and lesser than or equal to 9 by 3.

```
  List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(3, 6, 9, 12, 15);
  list.stream().map(number -> number * 3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This one multiplies everything by 3 , where

```
list.stream().filter(number -> number>3).map(number -> number * 3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

this one multiplies but also filters.

I want 3 ,6 ,9 multiplied by 3 and 12, 15 multiplied by 2.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why is `9` multiplied by 3? "lesse than 9 by 3" does not include `9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone don't like the ternary operator in Eran's answer, you could use a block instead, like this:

```
list.stream()
  .map(n -> {
     if (n > 9){ 
        return n * 2; 
      }
      else { 
        return n * 3; 
      }
    })
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

I think the solution with ternary operator is cleaner in this specific case but this is an option as well. It might be useful if there are more conditions.

Comment: This will be useful if there are more conditions

Comment: wouldn't a normal loop be more appropriate if using this?

Comment: @user85421 I believe the idea of the question was to use a stream for this, perhaps for the learning purposes. Or it might be a simplified case just for SO and OP wants to do more operations on the stream afterwards.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam plus this is the one which shows what OP might have missed so far: lambdas are actual functions with a body.

Answer (score 6):

You can combine the `filter` and `map` steps:

```
list.stream()
    .map(n -> n > 9 ? n * 2 : n * 3)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: @user85421 `I want 3 ,6 ,9 multiplied by 3 and 12, 15 multiplied by 2`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this.
You don't need a filter , you are mapping with a condition.

```java
list.stream()
    .map(number -> number > 9 ? number * 2 : number * 3)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```